# PreferenceScreen. сделать выбор категорий и параметров из JSON

Tags: java, android, json

делаю свой клиент для авито. все бы ничего, но вот уже неделю не могу допереть как реализовать выбор категорий как в офф клиенте. то есть выбираешь категорию, показывается список дочерних категорий, выбираешь дочернюю, показывается список параметров этой категории. и самое непонятное, как отделить категорию от параметров... то есть как отделить последнюю выбранную категорию "резюме" от параметров "График, сфера деятельности" и т.п. Все это толкается в PreferenceScreen в виде динамического ListPreference.
вот пример JSON строчки с категориями. тянется с сайта

```
[
  {
    "id": "175",
    "title": "Вид одежды",
    "type": "select",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "747",
        "title": "Женская одежда",
        "params": [
          {
            "id": "83",
            "title": "Предмет одежды",
            "type": "select",
            "values": [
              {
                "id": "240",
                "title": "Брюки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "85",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "258",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "259",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "260",
                        "title": "44–46 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "261",
                        "title": "46–48 (L)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "262",
                        "title": "48–50 (XL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "263",
                        "title": "> 50 (XXL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "264",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "241",
                "title": "Верхняя одежда",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "86",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "265",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "266",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "267",
                        "title": "44–46 (M)"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "242",
                "title": "Джинсы",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "87",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "272",
                        "title": "25"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "273",
                        "title": "26"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "281",
                        "title": "> 34"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5100",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "4829",
                "title": "Купальники",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "490",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "5101",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5102",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5107",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "4830",
                "title": "Нижнее бельё",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "491",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "5108",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5109",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5110",
                        "title": "44–46 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "5114",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "243",
                "title": "Обувь",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "88",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "282",
                        "title": "< 35"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "283",
                        "title": "36"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "288",
                        "title": "> 41"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "244",
                "title": "Пиджаки и костюмы",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "89",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "289",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "290",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "291",
                        "title": "44–46 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "292",
                        "title": "46–48 (L)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "293",
                        "title": "48–50 (XL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "294",
                        "title": "> 50 (XXL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "295",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "245",
                "title": "Платья и юбки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "90",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "296",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "297",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "302",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "246",
                "title": "Рубашки и блузки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "91",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "303",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "304",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "308",
                        "title": "> 50 (XXL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "309",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "4828",
                "title": "Свадебные платья",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "476",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "4860",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "4861",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "4866",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "247",
                "title": "Топы и футболки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "92",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "310",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "311",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "316",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "248",
                "title": "Трикотаж",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "93",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "317",
                        "title": "40–42 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "318",
                        "title": "42–44 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "323",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "249",
                "title": "Другое"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "748",
        "title": "Мужская одежда",
        "params": [
          {
            "id": "176",
            "title": "Предмет одежды",
            "type": "select",
            "values": [
              {
                "id": "750",
                "title": "Брюки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "95",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "332",
                        "title": "44–46 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "333",
                        "title": "46–48 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1002",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "751",
                "title": "Верхняя одежда",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "96",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "1012",
                        "title": "42–44 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "338",
                        "title": "44–46 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "339",
                        "title": "46–48 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1001",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "752",
                "title": "Джинсы",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "97",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "344",
                        "title": "29"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "345",
                        "title": "30"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "346",
                        "title": "31"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "347",
                        "title": "32"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "943",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "753",
                "title": "Обувь",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "98",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "351",
                        "title": "< 40"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "352",
                        "title": "41"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "353",
                        "title": "42"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "354",
                        "title": "43"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "355",
                        "title": "44"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "356",
                        "title": "45"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "357",
                        "title": "> 46"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "754",
                "title": "Пиджаки и костюмы",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "99",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "5098",
                        "title": "42-44 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "358",
                        "title": "44–46 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "359",
                        "title": "46–48 (M)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "363",
                        "title": "> 54 (XXXL)"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "942",
                "title": "Рубашки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "194",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "1010",
                        "title": "42–44 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1003",
                        "title": "44–46 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1009",
                        "title": "> 54 (XXXL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1005",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "756",
                "title": "Трикотаж и футболки",
                "params": [
                  {
                    "id": "101",
                    "title": "Размер",
                    "type": "select",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "id": "5099",
                        "title": "42-44 (XS)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "370",
                        "title": "44–46 (S)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "375",
                        "title": "> 54 (XXXL)"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1011",
                        "title": "Без размера"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "757",
                "title": "Другое"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "749",
        "title": "Аксессуары"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

пробовал толкать в разные коллекции, но рекурсией параметры и категории сливаются. в общем я в ступоре

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что на самом деле ваш вопрос звучит так: "Как сконвертировать этот JSON в модель?"

Answer (score 2):

Делал что-то подобное, использовал паттерн [Компоновщик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)):

Вся структура данных у нас в виде дерева, каждый узел или лист дерева это категория:

```
public interface ICategory {
    void goInto();
}
```

Изначально у нас есть ListView, в адаптере которого содержится список из `ICategory`. Когда кликаем по категории вызывается `goInto()`, Если это `ParentCategory`, реализация заменяет в адаптере список категорий, на дочерние.

```
public class ParentCategory implements ICategory {

    private List<ICategory> mChilds = new ArrayList<ICategory>();


    @Override
    public void goInto() {
        //заменяем текущие категории адаптера на mChilds 
    }
}
```

Самая последняя категория у нас обладает другой логикой

```
public class LeafCategory implements ICategory {

    @Override
    public void goInto() {
       //открываем последнюю выбранную категорию
    }
}
```

Те изначально мы должны спарсить весь жсон в эту древовидную структуру и потом работать как описал выше.